# Odd "pulsed" acceleration when using amcl and move_base

Tags: navigation, move-base, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am trying out amcl and move_base on a new home built robot that is similar to the TurtleBot but uses the Serializer microcontroller and Pololu motors and encoders.  I also have a Hokuyo laser scanner.

I'm running the odometry loop at 20Hz and the robot can do dead reckoning fairly nicely.  Next I created a small map of a couple of rooms using gmapping and that also looks good.

The trouble occurs when I then run amcl and move_base and set a navigation goal in RViz. The robot always gets to the goal fine and follows the planned path fairly well.  However, as it is moving it does a kind of pulsed acceleration and deceleration, even when it is moving across a complete clear space. The frequency of the pulsing is about 2 seconds. Is this something that could be tweaked somewhere in the base local planner parameters?  I am basically using the TurtleBot parameters for the planner and the cost maps so I won't post them here.

Thanks!
patrick

**UPDATE: Jan 1, 2012**: It seems I spoke too soon.  I am still getting oscillations in cmd_vel as sent to the robot by move_base.  I have posted a [bag file here](http://www.pirobot.org/downloads/oscillating_cmd_vel_2012-01-01-09-33-01.bag) demonstrating the phenomenon.  I am running move_base with a blank map and fake localization.  Then I set a nav_goal about a meter ahead and slightly to the right of the robot in an otherwise clear area.  If you rxplot cmd_vel you can see the oscillations in the x component which are very noticeable when watching the robot.  For move_base, I am using essentially the identical parameters as in the turtlebot_navigation package.

Can anyone see the cause of this oscillation--perhaps some kind of asynchronization between /odom and /cmd_vel?

**Update 2**: Here is an rxplot of /cmd_vel/linear/x and /odom/twist/twist/linear/x with the robot up on blocks so the wheels are spinning with no resistance:

[image: rxplot of cmd_vel and odom]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12490/odd-%22pulsed%22-acceleration-when-using-amcl-and-move_base/) by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 4046 on 2011-12-30

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on 2012-01-04**:
@Eric Perko - I was not able to create the rxplot on the running robot either--then I discovered that I was not publishing a timestamp on the odom message header.  Once I added the timestamp, I was able to get the plot.  Unfortunately, adding the timestamp did not fix the oscillation problem.

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2012-01-03**:
@Pi Robot: Just curious - are you able to create the rxplot while playing back from the bag file you posted or only against the running robot?

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2012-01-01**:
@Pi Robot: Can you plot `rxplot /cmd_vel/linear/x,/odom/twist/twist/linear/x` against the live system while you are seeing the oscillations? I can't seem to get it to plot on the same graph on your bag file, and this graph is the one that I think would be most illuminating.

**Comment by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on 2011-12-31**:
Thanks @ahendrix and @Eric Perko.  I looked at cmd_vel/linear/x in rxplot and the robot was definitely being sent an oscillating velocity command.  Since I wrote the odometry node for the Serializer I figured that was the weakest link. ;-)  So I went back to the code and sure enough, I had used Python time() instead of rospy.Time() when computing and publishing odometry messages.  Once I fixed that bug, the oscillations disappeared.  So I'm guessing I had a small time synchronization error between odom messages and move_base.

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-12-30**:
Have you looked at an rxplot of cmd_vel/linear/x and /odom/twist/twist/linear/x while this pulsing is going on? Do the commands pulse because of weirdness in the reported velocity or do the reported velocities pulse to follow pulsing commands?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From comment above: Thanks @ahendrix and @Eric Perko. I looked at cmd_vel/linear/x in rxplot and the robot was definitely being sent an oscillating velocity command. Since I wrote the odometry node for the Serializer I figured that was the weakest link. ;-) So I went back to the code and sure enough, I had used Python time() instead of rospy.Time() when computing and publishing odometry messages. Once I fixed that bug, the oscillations disappeared. So I'm guessing I had a small time synchronization error between odom messages and move_base

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-12-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on 2012-01-01**:
@ahendrix and @Eric Perko -- please see Update to my original question.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've seen problems like this in the past when I've had multiple nodes publishing to the cmd_vel topic; usually move_base and teleop. move_base was sending movement commands, while teleop was sending stop. This usually manifested as stutter rather than pulsing.

An easy check would to be rostopic echo cmd_vel and look at what commands are being sent. You could also use rxgraph to look at individual fields in cmd_vel.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2011-12-30

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [chedanix](https://answers.ros.org/users/33642/chedanix/) on 2018-02-20**:
Thank you sir!!!   I included teleop in my launch file and I completely forgot about it. It was secretly sending zero velocity commands the entire time!